# Looking for a straightforward library to implement hover-based dropdown menus in a MERN website

Tags: reactjs, menu, dropdown, e-commerce

I'm currently working on an e-commerce website using the MERN stack, and I'm looking for a simple and easy-to-use library to implement dropdown menus. Specifically, I have horizontal bar with 7 main category products topics, and when I hover over each category, I'd like to display a dropdown menu with subcategories related to that specific category.
Can anyone suggest me some library or a nice way to do that ?

I'm wondering if there's a library that simplifies this process and provides a clean solution for handling hover-based dropdowns in a React.js application. I've looked into evergreen/semantic/react-bootstrap library, but no one of that helped me. I'm open to other recommendations based on your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked [Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/)? It provides components like [Select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) and [Popper](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-popper/) that match your description.

Comment: Yes but they dont have an hover-based option for that